# Replace character in the whole dataframe

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this:

```
a <- c(rep ("C-B", 4), rep("C_C", 6))
b <- c(rep ("B-B", 4), rep("B_C", 6))
c <- c(rep ("A-B", 4), rep("A_C", 6))
data1 <- data.frame (a, b, c)
```

I would like to replace in the whole dataframe the "_" with "-"

I tried this but it does not work properly:

```
data2 <- gsub('_', '-', data1)
```

What should I change?

Comment: you might need to loop over every column `data1[] <- lapply(data1, function(x) gsub('_', '-', x))`

Comment: Above dupe target is not correct

Comment: @Sotos should be correct now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [lapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/lapply) as follows

```
> data1 <- data.frame(lapply(data1, function(x) {gsub("_", "-", x)}))
```

or even better

```
> data1[] <- lapply(data1, function(x) {gsub("_", "-", x)})
> data1
     a   b   c
1  C-B B-B A-B
2  C-B B-B A-B
3  C-B B-B A-B
4  C-B B-B A-B
5  C-C B-C A-C
6  C-C B-C A-C
7  C-C B-C A-C
8  C-C B-C A-C
9  C-C B-C A-C
10 C-C B-C A-C
```

Comment: No need to call `data.frame`. You can update existing data frame. See Ronak's comment